# connect to a machine inside the intranet from outside with same address used inside

Tags: domain-name-system, hosts, intranet

I have a server inside my intranet, in wich i have apache running with some web applications.

when i'm at office the url i use to connect is zeus.mydomain.it, it works couse i have in my /etc/hosts a record 192.168.0.11 zeus.mydomain.it, but obviously it does not work when i'm outside in different network.

i have a internet connectino with static ip, so i can connect to my intranet form outside.

**the question is:** how can i connect to the intranet server using zeus.mydomain.it from inside and from outside my intranet ?

thanks!!
Pietro.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to make this work, but it requires the assistance and approval of the person running your network:

Make your internal servers publicly visible on the internet, and use that public address all the time.  You could multi-home the server by configuring a second ethernet interface on the machine with a public IP address and connecting that interface to the switch that connects your server to the outside world.  Then when outside requests to that public IP address came in to your network they would go straight to your server.  You have to be very careful to set up firewall rules and security on your system for this configuration. You can then access the machine as the same dns name inside and out.

Another way to achieve much the same effect is to use a vpn such as [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) to connect to your network remotely.  With this setup, some or all of your network traffic from your remote machine is tunneled into your network, in effect putting your system on to your office network from home. This means that when the vpn is running, you can connect directly to `zeus.mydomain.it` from your home machine.  This solution also requires the assistance of the administrator of your office network to set up.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to have the domain `zeus.mydomain.it` resolving to a public (Internet) IP address. Usually done at your registrar (most of them allow to create subdomains, like `zeus`, and assign an IP address to it in DNS configuration)

   2. you need the router/firewall of your office, the one that makes the interface between the Internet and intranet, to route the frames up to the internal server, usually via NAT-masquerading first (since your LAN is on a private network 192.168.0.0/16), but it is likely it does that already. Then you need to map the HTTP port (80) from the WAN side of the router, up to your local server 192.168.0.11, if not taken/used already...